# UIPinchGestureRecognizer to resize custom UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I created a custom UIView and I am trying to have UIPinchGestureRecognizer handle the resize of it.
But when I test my code the text is being resized when pinch and the frame is still the same size.

in floatingToolbar.m

```
-(void) pinchFired:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGFloat scale = [recognizer scale];

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(floatingToolbar:didPinchWithScale:)]) {
            [self.delegate floatingToolbar:self didPinchWithScale:scale];
        }

        [recognizer setScale:scale];
    }
}
```

in SBViewController.m

```
-(void) floatingToolbar:(SBAwesomeFloatingToolbar *)toolbar didPinchWithScale:(CGFloat)scale{
    NSLog(@"Scale is ------  %f",scale);   
    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);
    toolbar.transform = newTransform;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two issues:

#### Updating the Scale

First, I think you want to change `[recognizer setScale:scale]` to `recognizer.scale = 1`. Otherwise the size will change exponentially instead of linearly as the user continues to pinch.

For example, with `.scale = 1`, your log will look something like:

```
Log                       Transform Scale

                          1
Scale is ------  0.98     0.98
Scale is ------  0.99     0.97
Scale is ------  0.98     0.95
Scale is ------  0.98     0.93
```

With your current approach (which doesn't change the scale at all), your log will look like:

```
Log                       Transform Scale

                          1
Scale is ------  0.98     0.98
Scale is ------  0.92     0.90
Scale is ------  0.88     0.79
Scale is ------  0.83     0.65
```

This is bad because your view will shrink way too fast.

#### Use of `CGAffineTransformScale`

`CGAffineTransformScale` (and the other `CGAffineTransform`s) don't update the frame.

From the [`UIView` class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/transform) on the `transform` property:

> **WARNING**: If this property is not the identity transform, the value of the frame property is undefined and therefore should be ignored.

If you're relying on `frame` for your toolbar, you could just modify the toolbar's `frame` by multiplying `scale` against its height and width.